# Automation Scripts Fail when RDP(VM) is minimized

Tags: python, selenium, autoit, sikuli

I have been facing issue with automation execution of my script on one of the VM. I have automated the functionality of Saving a Document which is ideally a Windows Designed UI. I have  tried using various technologies/tools like AutoIT, Python, Sikuli but the script halts if VM is minimized. It works perfectly fine is VM is open via RDP and I can see runtime execution. But If I minimize the RDP, the script halts at 'Save As' dialog box, none of the send keys (Cntrl+s) or (Enter) work via AutoIt script. Please help with some solution so as to have successfully execution of script even in minimized mode.

Comment: Sikulis is actually processing whatever physically appears on the screen. If it's not there, Sikuli won't "see" it.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why your script fails when it gets executed over a minimized RDP session is quite simple. GUI automation/testing tools need to have an unlocked, active desktop - otherwise the operation system thinks that it doesn't need to actually render GUI operations (which is time consuming) since there no user can that can see the rendered graphical user interface anyway. And programs don't communicate via GUIs normally ...

This is why QF-Test and other GUI automation/testing tools often have a note in their FAQs describing this kind of problem. For example FAQ 14 in the case of QF-Test, see https://www.qfs.de/qf-test-handbuch/lc/manual-en-faq.html

As described in the FAQ 14 on Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016 and in case of an RDP connection you need to modify the Registry. Go to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
```

and add a new value

```
RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized as DWORD having the value 2
```

After restarting you will then be able to minimize the RDP connections. However disconnecing or closing the RDP connection will probably still result in a failure.

Comment: Thanks I do agree, But is this behavior also expected with tools AutoIT and Sikuli as well? How about Python encoding to open the window and send controls to Save As dialog?

Comment: Also I would like to mention that some of my scripts do work in minimized mode, I am facing issues only with this Window Based GUI component 'Save As' dialog which is automated using AutoIt.

Comment: @ArtiChetwani But is this behavior also expected with tools AutoIT and Sikuli as well? - Yes, it is affecting all GUI testing/automation tools not only AutoIt, Sikuli, ... to a certain degree every GUI testing/automation tool needs the operation system and if the operation system does not want to do anything then no tool will help you - If you need a GUI then you are NOT allowed to use a minimized or locked session. It is as simple as that. And there are many workarounds via VMs etc., see the FAQ I linked.

Comment: @ArtiChetwani How about Python encoding to open the window and send controls to Save As dialog? - This will not work either. It may be that "sending the control" is already affected.

Comment: @ArtiChetwani Also I would like to mention that some of my scripts do work in minimized mode, I am facing issues only with this Window Based GUI component 'Save As' dialog which is automated using AutoIt. ... Yes, I didn't say that the operation system fully prevents any GUI related operations. However you are not sure which of them it will get "blocked". So if you're executing your script 100 times, it may be that it fails only 1% of the time or 99% of the time. However there are certain operations which are more likely to fail then others.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running `tscon.exe RDP-Tcp#0 /dest:console` as admin as mentioned [here](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/keeping-computer-unlocked.html). This will disconnect your RDP connection but should leave all GUI programs running normally on the VM. I have personally used this with autoit on a VM and it worked OK. Of course you will not be able to monitor your script as it runs so this may or may not work for you.